# No SUCCESS constant in Command class

Tags: symfony4

I am developing a Symfony 4 command and when it finishes I want to return with a success or failure code.

[Here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html) is the documentation.

It says:

```
// return this if there was no problem running the command
// (it's equivalent to returning int(0))
return Command::SUCCESS;
```

using `Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command`.

I've checked that file, and there is no `SUCCESS` constant.

Am I miss something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this constant, you need have got a Symfony version 5.1 : [image]

Else for your Symfony 4.4, you can use directly integer.

```
Symfony 5.1
return Command::SUCCESS;

Symfony 4.4
return 0;
```

---

```
Symfony 5.1
return Command::FAILURE;

Symfony 4.4
return 1;
```